# What does the getBootStrapPart() - Method of the PagebookView - Class do?

Tags: java, eclipse, view, rcp

I'm working on an Eclipse RCP Project and are somehow stuck in my understanding of the method

`getBootStrapPart()` of the `PagebookViewClass`. Do i get this right, that when the part, that this method returns, is initialised the `PagebookView` is also initialised?

Example:

```
@Override
protected IWorkbenchPart getBootstrapPart() {
    IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
    IWorkbenchWindow activeWorkbenchWindow = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
    IWorkbenchPage activePage = activeWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage();
    return activePage.getActiveEditor();
}
```

Does this mean, whenever i get an active editor and that my Pagebookview is initialised?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getBootstrapPart() is called when the PageBookView is created. This determines which part to use during the initial creation. If you return null, then the defaultPage will be created.

See also: [How to create a PageBookView](http://www.eclipse-tips.com/how-to-guides/17-how-to-create-a-pagebookview)